# What is a good way to wrap this exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-boot-actuator

I am implementing a HealthIndicator for my springboot application which pings instances of Jenkins to check if they're up. I do this by pinging the `${JENKINS_URL}/login`. If it's up I get a 200 response. If it's not up, I get a very ugly stack trace like this:

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "html": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:574) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:966) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getCharset(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:224) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:165) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:345) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.path.to.package.JenkinsCache.pingJenkins(JenkinsCache.java:60) [classes/:na]
```

My driver code looks like this (in `JenkinsCache`):

```
private String pingJenkins(String jenkinsEndpoint) {
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     try{
            restTemplate.getForEntity(jenkinsEndpoint+"/login", String.class);
            return "OK";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An error occurred while pinging: "+jenkinsEndpoint, e);
        }
        return "DOWN";
    }
```

I'd rather catch a specific exception but if pinging a Jenkins Instance that is down produces an `InvalidMediaTypeException`, it looks a little confusing bit of code (i.e. I'd expect something like a `RestClientException`, etc). What is a good way to catch/handle this exception? Should I catch a `RuntimeException` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if *you* know that the expected Exception that comes back from this call is the `InvalidMediaTypeException` , the you simply crate a `RestClientException` and rethrow it to the caller that calls `pingJenkins`. Then, whomever uses your API will expect a `RestClientException`. Since this is Spring Boot, you could even use a global exception handler [enter link description here](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) that will catch that exception without you needing to.

```
public void callingMethod() {
    try {
        pingJenkins("http://www.jenkins-endpoint.com");
    } catch (RestClientException exception) {
        log.error("Could not connect to Jenkins", exception);
    } 
}

private String pingJenkins(String jenkinsEndpoint) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try{
        restTemplate.getForEntity(jenkinsEndpoint+"/login", String.class);
        return "OK";
    } catch (InvalidMediaTypeException exception) {
        throw new RestClientException("Pinging Jenkins failed: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    return "DOWN";
}
```

Comment: I see. `callingMethod()` doesn't have to handle the `RestClientException` - I just wanted to handle that exception in a meaningful way and in my testing I have *only* come across `InvalidMediaTypeException` and I don't know if I should expect any other kind of an exception

Comment: I'm actually surprised that you're getting that error, since the call to getForEntity is returning anything other than a RestClientException. Check out the Javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-

Comment: I know, right! I was expecting a RestClientException too!